# How do i display number-data from backend nodejs and express in a Badge

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to implement a Badge that displays a number-data from the database. This here is a snippet of my implementation :

```
<Tooltip title="Worker" aria-label="add">
        <Fab color="cyan" className={classes.fab}>
      <a href="#"> <IconButton color="white">
            <Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary">
            <Worker/>
            </Badge>
          </IconButton></a>
          </Fab>
      </Tooltip>
```

And I have the output as follows:

[image]

I'm importing the number-data from another component which fetches the data from the backend. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

## JSX

```html
<div className='cartIconContainer'>
  <span className='circle'>{this.props.cart.length}</span>
  <img src={require('./cart.png')} className='cartIcon'/>
</div>
```

## CSS

```css
.cartIconContainer{
  position: relative;
}
.circle {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight:200; 
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right: -5px;
}

.cartIcon{
  width: 25px;
}
```